# Gravatar doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial book "Ruby on Rails 5" creating a twitter-like app. I've set gravatar for user's profile picture in sample/app/app/helpers/user_helper.rb file:

```
def gravatar_for(user)
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  gravatar_url = "https//secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

Although, when I reload the user's page ( **localhost:3000/users/1** ) I can't see the gravatar itself, as if the image link is broken. How can I fix this? Here's my show file for html:

```
<%= provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class ="row">
 <aside class="col-md-4">
  <section class="user_info">
   <h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @user.name %>
   </h1>
  </section>
 </aside>
</div>
```

P.S. I'm using Google Chrome and it downloads every other image, so it doesn't seem like the problem is with the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is broken you're missing the colon after `https`

```
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you.